# In Pyspark, what happens when you groupBy the same column as you used in partitionBy?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that was partitioned by column `ID` and written to disk. This results in each partition getting its own folder in the filesystem. Now I am reading this data back in and would like to call `groupBy('ID')` followed by calling a `pandas_udf` function. My question is, since the data was partitioned by `ID`, is `groupBy('ID')` any faster than if it hadn't been partitioned? Would it be better to e.g. read one `ID` at a time using the folder structure? I worry the `groupBy` operation is looking through every record even though they've already been partitioned.

Comment: `group by` does look through every record unless you put a `where` clause. That will prune the partitions and only access the `ID`s which you specified

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic can you add some more detail, how would you use `where` before `groupBy`?

Comment: I mean, after you have the partitioned data, using `where` will be faster if you that filters by the same partition column. If you are using a `group by` on everything, you will still get same plan and same number of stages (shuffle will happen)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have partitioned by `ID` and saved to disk
2. You read it again and want to groupby and apply a pandas udf

It is obvious the `groupby` will look through every record, and so will most functions. But using a `pandas_udf` which `groupby("ID")` is going to be expensive because it will go through an unnecessary shuffle.

You can optimize performance by using `groupby` [`spark_partition_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id) since you have already partitioned by the column you want to groupby on.

#### EDIT:

If you want file names, you can try:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())
```

Comment: Is there something special you need to do for pyspark to recognize the directory structure as the partition structure? I tried reading mine in but the values for `spark_partition_id()` don't correspond to the expected folder names.

Comment: @cgreen I have added